# I need to create a input of four digits (all should be different and the first one should be 1)

Tags: javascript, html, regex, input

I want to check using "pattern" attribute that the user can't enter two similar digits like: 1232, 1222, 1229 etc.
After googling, I found something like this: `pattern="^1(?:([2-9])(?!\1))+$"`, but it doesn't work for 1232 (for example) and it doesn't consider how many digits you enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^(?!.*(\d).*\1)1\d{3}$
```

It works by requiring a 1, and then 3 more digits. It uses a negative lookahead to verify that a digit is not repeated anywhere in the 4 numbers.

Run the example below for test cases:

```js
let regex = /^(?!.*(\d).*\1)1\d{3}$/;

function test(numberAsString) {
  console.log(numberAsString, regex.test(numberAsString));
}

test('1232'); // false, number repeated
test('1222'); // false, number repeated
test('1229'); // false, number repeated
test('1234'); // true
test('2345'); // false, 1 does not start
test('1789'); // true
test('12345'); // false, too many digits
test('123'); // false, too little digits
```

**An explanation of the Regular Expression:**

```
1\d{3}
```

is the part that says it needs a 1, and then 3 more digits

```
(?!.*(\d).*\1)
```

is a [negative lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead) (note the `(?!`). It scans the entire input (`.*`), until it finds a digit (`\d`) that is captured (surrounded by `()`), and scans the rest of the string (`.*`), looking for a copy of itself (`\1`) or in other words, what the first capture was. In simpler terms, here is an example for a 1 that cannot be followed by a 1 at any point: `(?!.*1.*1)`. But since you are using a special character for any digit (`\d`), you can assert that any digit found is not repeated.

```
^
```

asserts the beginning of the string

```
$
```

asserts the end of the string. These beginning and ending assertions are needed so that strings like `asd1234` do not pass validation.

Comment: I don't understand the (?!.*(\d).*\1), so literally the above explanation was not much of use.

Comment: @user5676973, I've included a link to the basics of negative lookaheads. I also updated the explanation a little more to explain how this negative lookahead works.

Comment: well it worked fine, and thanks a lot for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
// Magical function.
var checkDigits = function(num, maxLength) {
    let allDigits = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    try {
        if (num.length < 1 || num.length > maxLength) throw new Error("You need to enter exactly " + maxLength + " digits");
        for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (allDigits[num[i]] === null) throw new Error("You repeated a digit in your sequence");
            allDigits[num[i]]  = null;
        }           
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return false
    }
    return allDigits;
};

// Getting data from dom.
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
// Trying to see the data in the console.
if (num[0] == 1) console.log(checkDigits(num.slice(1)));
```

Well that's all I could say, I hope you understood

EDIT: Oops I missed the one part sorry.

Cheers,
Rj

Comment: I'm not sure what this is trying to accomplish. Everytime I try to run this function (`ex checkDigits(1234, 4)`), the return value is always an array of digits 0-9. I would expect it to return `true` or `false` if it is valid or not.

Comment: ok, not exactly what i wanted. Firstly, I also thought to write a function, but here regular expressions are more practical.
I included that input in a form and when clicking on submit it runs the function (I called it onclick) and nevertheless it executes the function it redirects me to the next page, but I don't need that if the input is invalid

Comment: #KevBot The emphasis is not on the return value, if I input something that has a same number it throws an error, but at catch you might return false instead of null, that'd do what you were expecting. What's the point in returning true? returning that array already produces a truthy result. Except 0, false are false and all others are 'true' right and it also returns the digits that have been used and not have been used(may be its useful for later?)

Comment: yo #Viorel Casapu and #KevBot do you think I should delete my answer? and by the way #KevBot how come you could use two different matches on the same piece of string. You gave what not to find (?!) and then 1\d{3}? How did you do that does using parenthesis around the whole negative lookback had to do something with it?